# UITableViewDelegate cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a table view controller with a tableview that I set up in the storyboard with a push segue to it from the mapViewController.  When the user touched the ios provided annotation callout the function calloutAccessoryControllTapped is called, and it indirectly by way of a notification called

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SequeToConversationList" sender:self];
```

This works fine.

However, I replaced the ios supplied callout with a custom callout layed out in a XIB.  It has a button with an action that results in the same line of code above being executed, and the Segue to the tableView happens, however cellForRowAtIndexPath of the tableViewController never gets called. titleForHeaderInSection does however get called which indicates that it is acting as the UITableViewDataSource.

Anyone have any ideas?

Per code request:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhListTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "PhListTableViewController.h"
#import "PhSettings.h"

@interface PhListTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhListTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PhSettings *settings=[PhSettings getInstance];
    settings.currentViewController = CONV_LIST;

    //...

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    PhSettings *settings=[PhSettings getInstance];
    return [settings.myUUIDsList count];
}
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return @"Active:";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    PhSettings *settings=[PhSettings getInstance];
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString string];
    [s appendString:@"Alias:"];
    [s appendString:[[settings.myUUIDsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userAlias]];
    [s appendString:@"Category: "];
    [s appendString:[[settings.myUUIDsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] category]];

    cell.textLabel.text=s;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //indexPath.row
  // ...
}
```

@end

Comment: Did you link the delegate and dataSource in you XIB?

Comment: The XIB is only for the annotation's Custom Callout.  It doesn't have anything to do directly with initiating the segue.  That is done via a notification.   I.e. the user selects a button in the custom callout, some round trip server stuff happens, and when the callback for that completes a notification is sent to the mapViewController to initiate the segue.

Comment: Can you post the code how you custom the tableView? So we can dig in.

Comment: So before you `replaced the ios supplied callout`, everything work fine?

Comment: Yes everything worked before replacing the callout with a custom one, but ... It may be that numberOfRowsInSection is returning 0.  Checking now.

Comment: Seem like you forget to set the dataSource and delegate.

Comment: Try adding `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.dataSource = self` to viewDidLoad method.

Comment: no I didn't forget that was done via the storyboard, and I did try doing it in code as you are earlier but it didn't work.  I'm 99% sure now that it is the the settings.myUUIDList is empty and therefore numberOfRowsInSection is returning 0.  So it is programmer error on my part.  Thanks for suggesting that I post the code, it helped me to see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath may not be called because one(or more) of the following reasons:

1. numberOfRowsInSection returns 0
2. numberOfSectionsInTableView return 0
3. dataSource not properly set
4. heightForRowAtIndexPath returns 0
5. table has frame size of 0 for height and/or width

In your case my best shot is number 1(place a breakpoint in the method to see how many rows you are returning when table ask for rows count). My worst experience was with debugging number 5 :)