# No call to tableView:cellForRowAt:

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is a brief description of my issue: I have a VC that is the dataSource and delegate of a `UITableView` within it. Upon fetching data, the table should be updated. I can see that `tableView:heightForRowAt:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` are being called but no call is ever made to `tableView:cellForRowAt:`. Based on [this relevant StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27675487/7679591), I logged the `UITableView` frame from different parts of the code. Here is an excerpt from my logs (*text for clarity*):

```
successful message *update*
index 0 of 1 *1 item to display*
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) *this is called 1 line before reloadData on the main thread*
number rows: 1 
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) *this and the previous line are logged from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:*
size for row: 0 
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) *this and the previous line are logged from tableView:heightForRowAt:*
successful message *another update (~ 1 minute after previous line was logged)*
index 0 of 2 *2 items to display*
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) 
number rows: 2 
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) 
size for row: 0 
table frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

As you can see, `tableView:cellForRowAt:` is never called despite there being >0 sections, >0 rows, >0 row height, and the dataSource set correctly. I should note that this happens roughly 1/10 times that I use the app.

I figured maybe iOS believed the table to be hidden behind another layer, so I put a breakpoint in the `tableView:heightForRowAt:` method and used the Capture View Hierarchy feature to test. I have yet to see this issue when I debug this way. The table in question is always the foremost view.

Edit with code. The `itemsUpdated` method is successfully called after receiving a new message.

```
func itemsUpdated(upcoming: [Item]) {
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("index \(currentItem) of \(upcoming.count)")
    self.upcoming = upcoming
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("table frame: \(self.tableView.frame)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("size for row: \(indexPath.row)")
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("table frame: \(self.tableView.frame)")
    return indexPath.row == 0 ? tableView.frame.size.width+86.0 : 86.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("number rows: \(max(upcoming.count, 1))")
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("table frame: \(self.tableView.frame)")
    return max(upcoming.count, 1)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    DebugHelper.sharedInstance.log("cellForRowAt \(indexPath.row) upcoming: \(upcoming)", style: .weak)
    guard upcoming.count > 0 else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoItemTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
        highlightColorChanged(to: Item.defaultColor)
        return cell
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: indexPath.row == 0 ? "FirstItemTableViewCell" : "ItemTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ItemTableViewCell.")
    }

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.item = upcoming[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How are you updating the tableview after getting the data? Please show us some code.

Comment: Need to see code to help.

Comment: If you are not able to see your tableview while running app , then is an issue with constraints . could you please try to clear all the constraint & set them again?

Comment: The log clearly says "size for row: 0 ". Post your `heightForRow` function

Comment: Sorry for the misleading log. The "0" in "Size for row: 0" is actually `indexPath.row`. `tableView:cellForRowAt:` is also called regardless of cell size.